# Financial data source change

Tags: curated-data, finance

So I am using the command `FinancialData["name"]` to get the live price for any given stock. The openings are very important in my studies that I am conducting and it seems there is a delay of 10 to 15 mins on the data (at least during opening period).

I have checked the Mathematica's sources given in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/FinancialDataSourceInformation.html). What I wonder is that is it possible to change the sources manually? Suppose I set my source to Yahoo Stock so whenever I use the command I get the same data as Yahoo?

Answer (score 2):

You can't--unfortunately--change where the financial data comes from (the exception is with Bloomberg data and the Finance Platform product), but you can easily grab data from Yahoo Finance.

Here's an example grabbing the name, ask, and bid price of three companies:

```
yahoostockquote[tickers_] := Module[
 {ql = If[ListQ@tickers, StringRiffle[tickers, "+"], tickers]},
 Import["http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" <> ql <> "&f=nab"]]

yahoostockquote[{"AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"}]
```

> `{{"Apple Inc.", 128.78, 128.77}, {"Google Inc.", 537.11, 
>     536.94}, {"Microsoft Corporation", 46.24, 46.23}}`

We can expand this further for historical data by the following function:

```
yahoostockquote[ticker_?StringQ, fromdate_, todate_: Today] :=
 Module[{ffromdate = DateList[fromdate], ftodate = DateList[todate], querystring, return},
 querystring = "a=" <> ToString[ffromdate[[2]] - 1] <> "&b=" <> 
  ToString[ffromdate[[3]]] <> "&c=" <> ToString[ffromdate[[1]]] <> "&d=" <>
  ToString[ftodate[[2]] - 1] <> "&e=" <> 
  ToString[ftodate[[3]]] <> "&f=" <> ToString[ftodate[[1]]];
return = Import["http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" <> ticker <> 
 "&" <> querystring <> "&g=d&ignore=.csv"];
return[[2 ;;, 1]] = 
  DateObject[{#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}}, 
  DateFormat -> {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}] & /@ 
return[[2 ;;, 1]];
return
]

yahoostockquote["AAPL", {2015, 1, 1}, {2015, 2, 1}]
```

> [image]

Comment: When I run the code there is error! in the first section not even the second. are we sure it is right? I have error saying the url is not defined correctly! thanks

Comment: @William It works just fine for me. My guess is that you're not using version 10.1 so the function `StringRiffle` isn't yet available to you. Use `StringJoin@Riffle[tickers, "+"]` instead.